# Android: open hidden webview activity or fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

I'm developing an android app which shows a listview.
When the user clicks on an Item on the list, i need the app opens a regular activity with some details and, in background or in "hidden mode", opens a webview which load a URL (of my blog).

I need it because i want to trace which items are opened, analyzing the Google Analytics information on my blog; in this way, everytime someone clicks on an Item, i'll find the information on my blog.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need a hidden `WebView`? That serves no purpose at all - a `WebView` is to all a user to "view" a web page. Why don't you just perform an HTTP GET request using, for example, `HttpGet`?

Comment: If i have a simple HttpGet request, i receive only a kind of PING on the website, is it right? I need to receive other data too (e.g. how long was the visit on the item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to open a hidden webview is to call `webView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the OnCreate method